# Run commands on docker container and sync automatically with host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I Dockerkized a MENN(Nextjs) stack App, now everything works fine. I run into issues when i need to install npm packages. let me first show you the structure

**src/server/Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:14-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install -qyg nodemon@2.0.7
RUN npm install -qy
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

**src/client/Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:14-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install -qy
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

**src/docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:

  client:
    build: 
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - mern-network
    volumes:
      - ./client/src:/usr/app/src
      - ./client/public:/usr/app/public
    depends_on:
      - server
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_SERVER=http://localhost:5000
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    command: npm run dev
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
  
  server:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    networks:
      - mern-network
    volumes:
      - ./server/src:/usr/app/src
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://db:27017
      - CLIENT=http://localhost:3000
    command: /usr/app/node_modules/.bin/nodemon -L src/index.js

  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    networks:
      - mern-network
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db

networks:
  mern-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  mongo-data:
    driver: local
```

Now if i install any packages using the host machine it is as expected updated in package.json file and if run

```
docker-compose build
```

the package.json is also updated inside the container which is fine, but i feel like this kinda breaks the whole point of having your App Dockerized! , if multiple developers need to work on this App and they all need to install node/npm in their machines whats the point of using docker other than for deployments? so what I do right now is

```
sudo docker exec -it cebc4bcd9af6 sh //login into server container
```

**run a command e.g**

```
npm i express
```

it installs the package and updates package.json but the host package.json is not updated and if i run the **build** command again all changes are lost as Dockerfile copies in the source code of host into container, is there a way to synchronize the client and host? in a way that if i install a package inside my container that should also update the host files? this way i dont need to have node/npm installed locally and fulfills the purpose of having your App Dockerized!